Proper use of HttpClientFactory for large amount of concurrent requests
I have a .NET Core 8 project where i need to send large amount of concurrent request as fast as possible to a SOAP webservice. I am experiencing long responsetime when creating new HttpClient per request using the HttpClientFactory compared to using a single HttpClient registered as a singleton.
I have tried to follow the quidelines from [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines#recommended-use](microsoft), and i wanted to use the IHttpClientFactory because it comes with nice built in resiliency features.
However, i was experiencing 5-15 times longer response time when using the IHttpClientFactory compared to using a singleton HttpClient.

With singleton HttpClient: 4-8 seconds per request
With IHttpClientFactory method: 30-120 seconds per request

I can't figure out why this is happening but i must be doing something wrong. I am unable to reproduce the issue in a simple test project running on my own computer, but i can reproduce it in the production enviorment. In the production we have deployed the application as a windows service within a coporate network, and the webservice is reached trough a VPN Gateway.
Should i just use the singleton HttpClient and forget about the HttpClientFactory, or should i do something different when using HttpClientFactory?
Could this be a networking issue, and if so - how would i find out?
I have tried to create some simplified snippets of the code so you can see how i have implemented it.
Program.cs
...
//Registering the IHttpClientFactory
builder.Services.AddHttpClient().ConfigureHttpClientDefaults(x =>
{
    x.ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    {
        var socketHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler
        {
            MaxConnectionsPerServer = int.MaxValue,
            PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
        };
        return socketHandler;
    });
    x.ConfigureHttpClient(httpClient =>
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentLength", "411");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SOAPAction", "");
        httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);
    });
});

//Using a singleton HttpClient from the IHttpClientFactory instead of creating a new HttpClient per request
builder.Services.AddSingleton<HttpClient>(x => {
    return x.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient();
});
...

SendUpdateService.cs
//SendUpdateServiceUsingHttpClientSingleton.cs
//This one is fast!
internal class SendUpdateServiceUsingHttpClientSingleton : ISendUpdateService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private readonly ApiSettings _apiSettings;

    public SendUpdateServiceUsingHttpClientSingleton(HttpClient client, ApiSettings apiSettings)
    {
        _client = client;
        _apiSettings = apiSettings;
    }

    public async Task<string> SendUpdate(string pricingString)
    {
        var response = await _client.PostAsync(
           _apiSettings.BaseUrl,
            new StringContent(pricingString, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml"));
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}

SendUpdateService.cs
//SendUpdateServiceUsingFactory.cs
//This one is slow!
internal class SendUpdateServiceUsingFactory : ISendUpdateService
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
    private readonly ApiSettings _apiSettings;
    public SendUpdateServiceUsingFactory(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, ApiSettings apiSettings)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
        _apiSettings = apiSettings;
    }
    public async Task<string> SendUpdate(string pricingString)
    {
        using(var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient())
        {
            var response = await client.PostAsync(
                _apiSettings.BaseUrl,
                new StringContent(pricingString, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml"));
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}

ParallelProcessingService.cs
To handle the concurrency i use ActionBlock from System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow:
public static class ParallelProcessingService
{
    public static Task AsyncParallelForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, Task> body, int maxDegreeOfParallelism = DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded, TaskScheduler scheduler = null)
    {
        var options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallelism
        };
        if (scheduler != null)
            options.TaskScheduler = scheduler;

        var block = new ActionBlock<T>(body, options);

        foreach (var item in source)
            block.Post(item);

        block.Complete();
        return block.Completion;
    }

}

Worker.cs
On the worker i use the SendUpdateService to send the request. This is not the actual code but a test, and in production this i added as a HostedService. Furthermore, i am just sending the same simple string 10000 times to a mock webservice, but the way i am sending the request is the same as in the production code.
//Worker.cs
public class Worker
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    private readonly ISendUpdateService _sendUpdateService;
    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, ISendUpdateService sendUpdateService)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _sendUpdateService = sendUpdateService;
    }
    public async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        var arrayOfStrings = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            arrayOfStrings.Add("test");
        }


        ConcurrentBag<string> resultCollection = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
        const int maxDegreeOfParallelism = 20;

        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        await ParallelProcessingService.AsyncParallelForEach(arrayOfStrings, async (pricingString) =>
        {
            var result = await _sendUpdateService.SendUpdate(pricingString);
            resultCollection.Add(result);
        }, maxDegreeOfParallelism);

        stopwatch.Stop();

        _logger.LogInformation($"Total time taken: {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms using {nameof(_sendUpdateService)}");
    }
}

I created a local test project running in docker on . Here i used both a HttpClient singleton and IHttpFactoryClient

The responsetimes had no real difference when comparing methods.

I have also tried to deploy the same test on the production server with the same result

Again - as expected both method performed alike.

I tried to change back and forth between using the singleton and factory when using the production service trough the VPN Gateway.

Significant difference in performance where creating 1 HttpClient pre request from the HttpClientFactory causes slow responsetimes

Thank you all in advance!

"To handle the concurrency i use ActionBlock from System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow" - Parallel.ForEachAsync didn't work for you?

seems like in the one case you are adding some overhead by 1) creating a new client   2) disposing of client 3) Not using "await using" so IDisposableAsync can be used.  In the first method you're passing a reference in to a client that already exists.  No need to create or dispose of it.

Thank you all for the quick response.
@Fidor I went with the ActionBlock approach beacuse i found some good resources about it, and i did not know to much about Parallel.ForEachAsync. I think i could go ahead and replace the ActionBlock with Parallel.ForEachAsync to simplify the code, but to my knowledge they should work almost the same way so i simply just have not had the need to do it.
@browsermator I will try it out without disposing the client. I will post an update when i have some results!

According to your code snippet and description, In order  to optimize performance when sending large amounts of concurrent requests in a .NET Core 8 project, it's crucial to configure IHttpClientFactory properly and reuse HttpClient instances rather than creating a new one for each request. Define named clients with specific configurations, such as setting appropriate MaxConnectionsPerServer and PooledConnectionLifetime, to leverage connection pooling and DNS caching.

Additionally, test and monitor the network environment to identify potential issues like VPN-induced latency. This approach ensures efficient resource utilization and maintains high performance under concurrent load

I think doing this, is one of the problems:
using(var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient())

Because after leaving the block the httpClient will be disposed. Instead just try this without using:
var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

Also checkout my answer here.
